# Unable to configure custom attributes in okta

Tags: python, django, okta

I am facing problems while passing custom Attributes to the SP.

Details:
I am using developersOKTA admin profile for IDP.
My SP is a python application which user Django/jinja/Django-CMS

My app `attribute statement` value is this.

Attempt1:

> userName|${user.userName}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic, firstName|${user.firstName}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic, lastName|${user.lastName}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic, email|${user.email}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic, is_publisher|${template_saml_2_0.is_publisher}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic,  userRole|${template_saml_2_0.userRole}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic,

Where, **is_publisher**(type boolean) and **userRole**(type string) are custom attributes defined and given value on both places - in user profile and in app user profile. And **template_saml_2_0** is the app user object and **user** is the user object.

Next, I have mapped these variables together:

Mapping of okta->app

> user.is_publisher is mapped to is_publisher, and

Mapping of app->okta

> appuser.is_publisher is mapped to is_publisher.

Done similar for other attributes.

On click the app chiklet, with this attributes statement generates "500 internal server error". This error triggers before okta gives call to the SP. I have found nothing is logged in my SP's logs. And I do not know how to track OKTA IDP's logs.

Attempt2:.

Here I am taking values from the user object for the custom attributes, and rest keeping all same as in attempt 1.

> is_publisher|${user.is_publisher}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic, userRole|${user.userRole}|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic,

Now this change gives me the value of **userRole**(string type) and not for **is_publisher**(boolean type) in the assertion xml passed to the SP by OKTA. I guess this returns values if the custom attribute is only of string type and not for any others types. Is it the case?

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong? I need to set roles of users according the application which I have failed to do in Attempt1. and In Attempt2 I am only getting String type CustomAttribute's value.

Comment: Same issue here. I make a new custom "role" user attribute, then I try to reference it in the attributes using ${user.role}. Okta returns an Internal server error. Have you found a solution?

Comment: nope i did not.